# Close an external TCP connection

Tags: c#, tcp

How can I terminate a TCP connection which is not handled by my program?

for example I want to close all the connection on port 10202 and I don't want them to reopen, but I want to allow the other ports.
everything in C#.

like Sysinternals' tcpView does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to p/Invoke [`SetTcpEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366378(v=VS.85).aspx). TCPView uses Dark and Mysterious Methods to do the same even on platforms that don't support that function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how TCPView does it, but you could generate a TCP Fin packet and fire it at yourself.

I don't know how to do that in C#, but you might be able to find a way.